# Cannot from xml.dom import Element

Tags: python, xml

I cannot import Element Object from xml.dom even there is xml.dom.Element on xml official documentation.
[image]

[image]

Comment: have you reviewed the [xml.dom docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.html)? There is no `Element` module in the `xml.dom` module. The `xml.dom.Element` on `xml` official documentation from the [w3 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/) translates to the [class xml.etree.ElementTree.Element](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element). To understand further what modules are in `xml.dom` inspect the output of `print dir(xml.dom)`, there's no `Element` in this output.

Comment: this may better illustrate what you are expecting: https://repl.it/KmKD

Comment: @downshift Oh! Sorry, it is my fault. But there is also a Element object on xml.dom, I will attach the picture above.

Comment: That's okay, are you referring to the `Element` Interface listed here: [Objects in the DOM](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.html#objects-in-the-dom)

Comment: @downshift Yes, it is. What is the difference between them?

Comment: @downshift Actually, I expect there will be a `tag`,an `attrib` and so on in the print of `dir(elem)`, but it looks like there are just a bunch of function name in it which I expect to get attributes.

Comment: The difference is ElementTree (xml.etree) is a python API to access XML, while DOM (xml.dom) is a cross-platform, language independent standard. check this q&a, it probably explains it better than I could [xml.etree or xml.dom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11952713/xml-etree-or-xml-dom)

Comment: @downshift Thanks a lot.